# RoR 3 beginner, trouble with passing IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code works fine:

```
<table border="1">
    <% @allevents.each do |allevent| %>
        <tr>    
            <td><%= allevent.name %></td>
            <td><%= button_to "View", :action => "view", :allevent_id => "0000000000000131"%>
        </tr>
   <% end %>
</table>
```

However when I swap out the ID I'm passing to :

```
<%= button_to "View", :action => "view", allevent_id  %>
```

Its passing a nil value. Any idea how I can reference this correctly? It doesn't seem to like allevent.id but the allevent_id is nil? I tested displaying allevent.id in output text and it looked correct.

Controller code for reference:

```
def index
@allevents = Event.all     
end
```

Also wanted to add my routes.rb code which seems to vague:

```
match 'event/:action' => 'events#view'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<table border="1">
    <% @allevents.each do |allevent| %>
        <tr>    
            <td><%= allevent.name %></td>
            <td><%= button_to "View", :action => "view", :allevent_id => allevent.id %>
        </tr>
   <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that combo! It works, thanks. Does the routes.rb enty look right to you?

Comment: You should never refer to `model.id` outside of the database context. The correct method is `model.to_param` because sometimes these are customized to make the URLs more presentable.

Comment: yes I agree, I's also use `@events` or `@all_events` instead of `@allevents` and `event` in the cycle, if I correctly got the meaning of this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, try and stick with the RESTful naming conventions of `index`, `show` and so on. Using `view` creates needless complexity. Sometimes you will have a case where you can't map it to REST directly, so if that's the case by all means create new actions. "View" should be the same as "show".

Using `resource :events` should do 90% of what you want out of the box and you can customize it to not generate routes you don't need.

This has the additional effect of giving you named routing helpers that can simplify your links:

```
<%= button_to "View", event_path(allevent) %>
```

These are far more reliable than the manual routing method which is all too easy to get wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips. I changed it over to use show instead of view and use event_path instead. The only issue I'm having is now after clicking the button my url is filename.eventid instead of filename/eventid. If i change it manually in the URL it works fine. How can I fix this? I also changed my entry in routes.rb to: 

match 'event/:id' => 'events#show'

Comment: Usually that comes by mistakenly submitting a `:format` option instead of the correct route. I don't see any reference to `filename` in your example, though.